# Encoding AES output: Is there a standard way to add the IV to the cyphertext?

Tags: encryption, aes, standards

Are there any widely recognized standards around encoding the output of AES encryption?

More specifically, I'm looking for a standards based approach to encoding the IV with the cyphertext. i.e. is the IV pre-pended to the cyphertext byte array, appended, or stored seperatley. My end goal is to have a Base64 encoded string containing the IV and the cyphertext to allow for interoperability with other widely used AES libraries.

Comment: since the concept of an IV is nothing that is based upon AES but blockciphers in general, or to be more precise, their modes of operation, this question is a bit misleading ... whatever library you use, you will have to provide the IV to decrypt, and it is common practice to simply prepend the IV ... but a widely recognized standard? ... usually the interface spec tells you how to provide it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A widely recognized method is to prepend the IV to the encrypted data, the IV does not need to be secret.  But there is no "standard", that implies specified by a standards body.

There is no "standard" and no method that has interoperability between implementations, it is still the ["Wild West"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=The+Wild+West&defid=5254055) on implementations.

One solution that is implemented for several languages/platforms: [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), it also includes key derivation, authentication and v versioning.